# I'm looking for a chip which can play media files stored in a pen drive connected to it on LCD tv

Tags: lcd, programming, display, system-on-chip

I am searching for such a chip which has a usb input to connect a pen drive to it. The chip should have a HDMI output (or any other suitable output) to display on a LCD tv. For example, I have a movie stored in a pen drive which is connected to the chip and that chip's output is given to the LCD tv. On start up the chip should start playing the movie automatically on the tv. Please give me solutions for this requirement like name of such a chip, where can i get it, etc.

Comment: Hi Ameya, welcome to EE.SE. I removed the "Urgently required" from your question. We will attempt to answer your question as soon as someone with the knowledge and time can.

Comment: ok. I am hopeful i will get answers here

Comment: searched for something like this? http://english.kalingasblog.com/2009/10/htpc-intel-atom-media-center-inside-a-cd-player/

Answer (score 1):

A "chip" that does this with no other support is unlikely to be available. But, ...

There are a number of small, moderately low cost, self contained single-board or modular computers that do this with ease. One example is the $US25 "Raspberry Pi". This could meet your need with the Raspberry Pi itself, a programmed SD card, a 5V power supply (could be via USB cable or battery or other, and a video output cable.

---

Raspberry Pi:

[Home](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)

[FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)

Larger than life photo (probably). Actual size is about the same as a credit card. (Photo from Wikipedia).

[image]

[image]

[Element 14 purchase point](http://www.element14.com/community/groups/raspberry-pi) - people have received RPs.

[RS purchase point - MAY be available](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi&cm_mmc=UK-Short_url-_-Internal-Flyer-_-%20RaspberryPie-062012-_-Multimedia)

["Resources"](http://www.designspark.com/theme/raspberrypi)